# Django ldap module error "AttributeError: module 'ldap' has no attribute 'OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT'"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, ldap

I try to start my Django project and I catch this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/erastov/PycharmProjects/auction/auc_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/erastov/PycharmProjects/auction/auc_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 308, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/erastov/PycharmProjects/auction/auc_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/erastov/PycharmProjects/auction/auc_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/erastov/PycharmProjects/auction/auc_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/erastov/PycharmProjects/auction/auction/backend/auction/settings/dev.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import *
  File "/home/erastov/PycharmProjects/auction/auction/backend/auction/settings/base.py", line 86, in <module>
    ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT: ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER
AttributeError: module 'ldap' has no attribute 'OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT'
```

I use Python 3.5, Django 1.11.7, ldap 1.0.2

It's happening when I remove my local project and clone from github again.I installed all requirements as usual.

Part of code:

```
import os

import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, ActiveDirectoryGroupType

....

AUTH_LDAP_GLOBAL_OPTIONS = {
    ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT: ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code as it is difficult to work out what the problem is without seeing it.

Comment: I faced the same behavior after upgrading mac. I uninstalled `python-ldap` and installed it again and it worked after that. I am unable to understand this mystery yet.